# Incompatibility between input and final Dense Layer (Value Error)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm following this [tutorial](https://pub.towardsai.net/step-by-step-guide-in-creating-your-own-emotion-recognition-system-b8aba98134c8) from Nabeel Ahmed to create your own emotion detector using Keras (I'm a noob) and I've found a strange behaviour that I'd like to understand. The input data is a bunch of **48x48 images**, each one with an integer value between 0 and 6 (each number stands for an emotion label), which represents the emotion present in the image.

```
train_X.shape -> (28709, 2304) // training-data, 28709 images of 48x48
train_Y.shape -> (28709,) //The emotion present in each image as an integer, 1 = happiness, 2 = sadness, etc.
val_X.shape -> (3589, 2304)
val_Y.shape -> (3589, )
```

In order to feed the data into the model, `train_X` and `val_X` are reshaped (as the tutorial explains)

```
train_X.shape -> (28709, 48, 48, 1)
val_X.shape -> (3589, 48, 48, 1)
```

The model, as it is in the tutorial, is this one:

```
model = Sequential()
input_shape = (48,48,1)
#1st convolution layer
model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), input_shape=input_shape,activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

#2nd convolution layer
model.add(Conv2D(128, (5, 5),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (5, 5),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

#3rd convolution layer
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
################################################################
model.add(Dense(7)) # <- problematic line
################################################################
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

my_optimiser = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, amsgrad=False,
name='Adam')

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'],optimizer=my_optimiser)
```

However, when I try to use it, using the tutorial snippet, I get an error in the line of the `validation_data` like this

```
history = model.fit(train_X,     
        train_Y, 
        batch_size=64, 
        epochs=80, 
        verbose=1, 
        validation_data=(val_X, val_Y),
        shuffle=True)

ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 7) are incompatible
```

After reviewing the code and the documentation about the `fit` method, my only idea was to change the `7` in the last `Dense` layer of the model to 1, which mysteriously works. I'd like to know what is happening here if anyone could give me a hint.

Comment: could you inspect val_Y shape? Your last dense layer is correct with 7 neurons, because you have 7 classes (emotions). Maybe val_Y has shape of one (number between 0 and 6). In this scenario, you should arg_max your result from neural network.

Comment: `val_Y` is an array of 3589 values, one integer per image. How would I apply the arg_max in this setting? I'm very new to ML @Henrique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be working with sparse integer labels, where each sample belongs to one of seven classes {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, so I would recommend using `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` instead of `CategoricalCrossentropy` as your loss function. Just change this parameter and your model should work fine. If you want to use `CategoricalCrossentropy`, you will have to one-hot encode your labels, for example with:

```
train_Y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(train_Y, num_classes=7)
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I found the code from the tutorial and there was a missing snippet where the author turns the output into categorical data with that function `to_categorical` but changing the loss function worked too, thank you very much!